# Is it possible to make the right mouse button do something else in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, mouse, key-mapping

I have a cheap 2 button mouse so wanted to turn the right mouse button into my gesture button (with Easystroke). Perhaps making a double right click act as a normal right click.